# I am getting 404 error code while performing post request , but the data is successfully getting inserted into the database on spring boot appilcation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I am performing the post/Delete operation from postman, I am getting 404 error code ,but the data is successfully getting inserted or deleted into my database. I am unable to understand why my code is behaving like this. Sharing screenshot
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoxbl.png),
[api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8plfC.jpg)

Controller class

```
    @Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/user/add")
 public void addNewUser(@RequestBody User user) throws BLException {
     userService.addNewUser(user);
 }

  @DeleteMapping("/user/delete/{id}")
    public void deleteById(@PathVariable int id){
        userService.deleteById(id);

  }

  @DeleteMapping("/deleteAll")
    public void deleteAll(){
        userService.deleteAll();
  }
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
   public UserRepository userRepository;

    public void addNewUser(User user) throws BLException {
        try {
            ValidateMobileNumber.validate(user.getPhone());
            userRepository.save(user);


        }
        catch (BLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void deleteById(int id){
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    public void deleteAll(){
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

build.gradle file

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.3.16'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'



    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.6.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.22'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.6.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools', version: '2.6.3'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.9.8'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt
    implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.9.8'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance
    implementation group: 'aopalliance', name: 'aopalliance', version: '1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib
    implementation group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib', version: '3.3.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.asm/asm
    implementation group: 'org.ow2.asm', name: 'asm', version: '9.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.7.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.30'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '2.7.2'

    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'


}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on success of your action you can change the response result like this:

```java
@PostMapping("CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword")
    public void createUserWithEmailAndPassword(@RequestBody User newUser, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletResponse response) throws FirebaseAuthException {
        userService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser, password);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
```

you get the response parameter for "free" whenever you send a request.

if your request fails throw an error and and catch it in your exception handler, there assign the appropriate status code according to the reason of failure.

Another option for successful requests is to use this annotation: `@ResponseStatus`

you can learn more about this here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status

Comment: Thanks , this resolved my issue but why the api was giving 404 at first ? if the api post operation is successfull than I should see a 200 ok

Comment: This is the default behavior, you can also use the following annotation for successful requests: @ResponseStatus